COT CODE MONEY TRANSFER
There was a post from several years ago(2018) about being asked for a COT code to transfer money.  I am asking if there is an update on this.  Also does this also apply to international banking?
Thank you.

There's no such thing as "COT", or any other fee that you need to pay to get your own money. If anyone needs charge you for a transfer - they will deduct it from the amounts being transferred.

The COT code request is a sign of a scam. They want you to pay money to get the code so that they can send you your money. This hasn't changed.
They want to try and get even more money from you, thus this made up fee.
